Calculating the energy momentum tensor of $bc$ and $\beta\gamma$ CFT
I'm trying to calculate the energy momentum tensor of the $bc$ and $\beta\gamma$ CFT's, using a simple method of calculating the canonical expression and adding total derivatives (rather than the methods in this and this posts), I can reproduce the energy momentum tensor of $bc$ CFT, but not of the $\beta\gamma$ CFT. I follow the equations in Polchinski volume 1.
The action of the $bc$ CFT is given by Eq. (2.5.4):
$$
S=\frac{1}{2\pi}\intop d^{2}zb\bar{\partial}c.\tag{2.5.4}
$$
The canonical energy momentum tensor is given by: (Francesco (2.165))
$$
T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\left(\partial^{\mu}\Phi\right)}\partial_{\nu}\Phi-\eta_{\mu\nu}L\tag{2.165}
$$
working in the $z,\bar{z}$ coordinate system, we have that
$$T_{zz}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\left(\bar{\partial}\Phi\right)}\partial\Phi$$
The variation of the Lagrangian with respect to $\bar{\partial}c$ is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\left(\bar{\partial}c\right)}=-b$ (the minus sign is because b and c anti commute), and we get that:
$$T_{zz}=-b\partial c$$
This is also the result in Francesco Eq. (5.118). This is not the expression in Polchinski which is Eq. (2.5.11a)
$$
T_{zz}=\partial bc-\lambda\partial\left(bc\right)
$$
but we can add a total derivative $\left(1-\lambda\right)\partial\left(bc\right)$ to get:
$$
T_{zz}=-b\partial c+\left(1-\lambda\right)\partial\left(bc\right)=-b\partial c+\partial bc+b\partial c-\lambda\partial\left(bc\right)=\partial bc-\lambda\partial\left(bc\right)
$$
and this is the same as in Polchinski.
Trying to repeat the same steps for the $\beta\gamma$ CFT does not seem to work. The action is (Eq. (2.5.20)):
$$
S=\frac{1}{2\pi}\intop d^{2}z\beta\bar{\partial}\gamma
$$
The variation with respect to $\bar{\partial}\gamma$ is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\left(\bar{\partial}c\right)}=\beta$ (without a minus sign, since $\beta$ and $\gamma$ commute), and so the energy momentum tensor becomes:
$$
T_{zz}=\beta\partial\gamma
$$
(This is also the expression in 0708.4261 chapter 3, Eq. 6, page 6, though it is just from searching for searching the web, and I do not know if it is not a typo there).
Adding a total derivative of $\left(-1-\lambda\right)\partial\left(\beta\gamma\right)$ will cause
$$
T_{zz}=-\partial\beta\gamma-\lambda\partial\left(\beta\gamma\right)
$$
which have a wrong minus sign compared to polcinski Eq. (2.5.23a):
$$
T_{zz}=\partial\beta\gamma-\lambda\partial\left(\beta\gamma\right)
$$
Is there a mistake in my calculation?
If there is no mistake, why this simple approach of using the canonical expression of $T_{zz}$ and adding total derivatives works for the bc CFT but not for $\beta\gamma$? Was it pure luck in the first case?

If you like, you can get the full energy momentum tensor (or just that of the superghosts) in one go by following the procedure leading up to eqn 6.52 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.06355. This procedure is to start from the flat space worldsheet action, and deform the supercomplex structure as explained there. If you have any further questions let me know.

It is much more efficient to work with the superfields rather than split it into components
